# Is it possible to call rest API using PHP, inside GAE for putting data at pull queue?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, task-queue

Is it  possible to call rest API using PHP, inside GAE for putting data at pull queue ??
I am trying to call rest api to put data at pull queue but I get an error

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => forbidden
                            [message] => you are not allowed to make this api call
                        )

                )

            [code] => 403
            [message] => you are not allowed to make this api call
        )

)
```

Comment: it is possible, what you have is an `accessDenied` error.  Did you authenticate properly?

Comment: As authentication I send API_KEY and Authorization from header

My target URL : https://content.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta2/projects/s~PROJECT_NAME/taskqueues/TASK_QUEUE_NAME/tasks

Comment: At local machine my code run successfully , but inside GAE it is not running

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try my PHP Pull Queue library for App Engine.
https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue

It's in very early ALPHA, but might work for you.

Removes the need for the REST API entirely. Uses native Google Protocol Buffers (same as the Python/Java/etc. runtimes)

Tom

Comment: hi.. is there any way to list tasks using your library??

Comment: Not currently. Feel free to raise an issue on the GitHub repo asking for the feature.

Comment: I have posted a issue on the GitHub repo .
https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue/issues/3

Comment: I have added a basic `listTasks()` method.

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue#list-tasks

I've also added the ETA to the Task object. Not sure how this will play out on Live AppEngine, which is 32-bit only. I've not run any tests.

Comment: listTasks() method working well.. But my requirement is list and get tasks

Comment: Please define your requirements in more detail. And probably over on GitHub